# How can a Metro app communicate over a serial port and not over USB?

Tags: serial-port, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I have a requirement that the device must be recognized over a serial port and not USB. :( Any ways for my Metro app to communicate over a serial port and not over USB? Just to clarify, I cannot use the example provided [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/USB-CDC-Control-sample-5ba19caa/view/Discussions). I really need the device to be recognized over a serial port.

Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: No, serial ports are not supported in WinRT.  They never will.

Comment: Why does your application require that the device interface as a serial port and not a USB device?

Comment: Our partner vendor needs the device to be exposed over a serial port.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people asking this very question are trying to communicate with a microcontroller such as Arduino. Windows Store Apps do not have and API for serial or parallel ports.
Quote from Microsoft employee: 
"This isn’t a scenario we targeted.  The option of last resort – is you write a custom driver, which isn’t an option for everyone, and even then it can only be accessed by one privileged app declared in device metadata.   A desktop app may be a better answer."
Search "serial ports in Windows store apps" at msdn.com and you will find this is a very common response.

Comment: I updated my comment when I realized the person wanted serial port and not Virual port over USB. Same idea, Microsoft says no support:(